# Where to get info on VS2010SP1

Tags: visual-studio

Now that release of VS2010SP1 is announced, i'm eager to see what it is offering fresh. Where can I get a comprehensive list of new features, changes from previous version etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason Zander (vice-president of the Visual Studio team) has a [list of fixes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/12/20/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta-feedback.aspx) on his blog (dated 20th December 2010). This appears to be more detailed than the list on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442059.aspx).

This is not for the RTM of SP1 though, as that is not yet in the final stages of the release. He has said he will publish an updated list when SP1 is released, so keep an eye on his blog.